# Clean way of adding HTML inside a Javascript object property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

Here's some Javascript I use to create a widget on my site:

```
var boxText = document.createElement("div");
boxText.class = "infobox-custom";
boxText.style.cssText = "margin-top: -215px; margin-left: -500px; border-radius: 10px; background-color:#438BC0; padding: 5px; height: 400px; width: 600px;";

// Notice this:
boxText.innerHTML = '<p>Some text.</p>';
```

Pretty simple. I need to set the `.innerHTML` to something much more complex and just sploshing it into a single line in Javascript doesn't feel right. It smells - at least to me.

What are my options here?

Can I have a PartialView and return that from my Controller to a jQuery POST request?

What do you recommend?

Comment: Where is this HTML coming from? (that you want to put in boxText)

Comment: @bradley.ayers: I would like to define a template (partial view), pass in a Model (to populate values, etc) and return that template as HTML.

Comment: Don't you mean `boxText.className` rather than `boxText.class`? (And since you seem to be using jQuery, why not `$("<div></div>").addClass("infobox-custom").css(/*yourCSShere*/).append("<p>Some text.</p>");`? And why not set those styles in your stylesheet, given that you're assigning a class anyway?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest it seems like rendering the HTML and sploshing it into the single line is the simplest option, given what you've got so far.

If you want to get more serious about having the UI dynamic via JavaScript, you should look into using JavaScript to render a template, and simply serve up data (JSON) from your backend (ASP).

A few templating options:

- [underscore.js's builtin option](http://underscorejs.org/#template)
- [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com)
- [jquery-tmpl](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) (~deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

In order to create and use templates with jQuery you'll have to use a plugin. Here's the one that used to be under development from the jQuery team but doesn't seem to be anymore: [Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/).

> Note: The jQuery team has decided not to take this plugin past beta.
>   It is no longer being actively developed or maintained. The docs
>   remain here for the time being (for reference) until a suitable
>   replacement template plugin is ready.